# Cleaner way to handle double pointer in C++ BST?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I have an implementation for my first binary search tree in C++. I was wondering if there was some cleaner way to avoid using the double pointer in the way I have my code setup? Such as on one line I have:

```
(*node)->left = insert(&((*node)->left),value);
```

Which seems a bit "messy", but it almost seems necessary for the way I have implemented the BST. Maybe I am possibly missing a way I can change the syntax slightly to achieve the same result? I understand that I can have a double pointer as a parameter for my functions, but I have been told that it is not the standard in C++. I have my code posted below, along with how I am testing it.I am trying to prepare for technical interviews so any feedback is welcome.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<iostream>
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    Node *left, *right; 
}; 

// A utility function to create a new BST node 
Node* newNode(int data) 
{ 
    Node *temp =  new Node(); 
    temp->data = data; 
    temp->left = NULL; 
    temp->right = NULL; 
    return temp; 
} 

// A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST 
void inorder(Node **root) 
{ 
    if (*root != NULL) 
    { 
        inorder(&((*root)->left)); 
        printf("%d \n", (*root)->data); 
        inorder(&((*root)->right)); 
    } 
} 

/* A utility function to insert a new node with given key in BST */
Node* insert(Node** node, int value) 
{ 
    if(*node==NULL){
        return newNode(value);
    }
    if((*node)->data > value){
        (*node)->left = insert(&((*node)->left),value);
    }
    else if((*node)->data < value){
        (*node)->right = insert(&((*node)->right),value);
    }
    return *node;
} 

// Driver Program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    /* Let us create following BST 
              50 
           /     \ 
          30      70 
         /  \    /  \ 
       20   40  60   80 */
    Node *root = NULL; 
    root = insert(&root, 50); 
    insert(&root, 30); 
    insert(&root, 20); 
    insert(&root, 40); 
    insert(&root, 70); 
    insert(&root, 60); 
    insert(&root, 80); 

    // print inoder traversal of the BST 
    inorder(&root); 

    return 0; 
}
```

**EDIT**: 
By changing " ** " in the parameters of the function to "*&" was able to make code much easier to read, with the same functionality.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<iostream>
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    Node *left, *right; 
}; 

// A utility function to create a new BST node 
Node* newNode(int data) 
{ 
    Node *temp =  new Node(); 
    temp->data = data; 
    temp->left = NULL; 
    temp->right = NULL; 
    return temp; 
} 

// A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST 
void inorder(Node *&root) 
{ 
    if (root != NULL) 
    { 
        inorder(((root)->left)); 
        printf("%d \n", (root)->data); 
        inorder(((root)->right)); 
    } 
} 

/* A utility function to insert a new node with given key in BST */
Node* insert(Node*& node, int value) 
{ 
    if(node==NULL){
        return newNode(value);
    }
    if((node)->data > value){
        node->left = insert(((node)->left),value);
    }
    else if((node)->data < value){
        (node)->right = insert(((node)->right),value);
    }
    return node;
} 

// Driver Program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    /* following BST 
              50 
           /     \ 
          30      70 
         /  \    /  \ 
       20   40  60   80 */
    Node *root = NULL; 
    root = insert(root, 50); 
    insert(root, 30); 
    insert(root, 20); 
    insert(root, 40); 
    insert(root, 70); 
    insert(root, 60); 
    insert(root, 80); 

    // print inoder traversal of the BST 
    inorder(root); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're trying to learn C++, you should get comfortable with constructors and destructors — they're what C++ is all about!

```
struct Node 
{ 
    int data; 
    Node *left, *right; 
}; 

// A utility function to create a new BST node 
Node* newNode(int data) 
{ 
    Node *temp =  new Node(); 
    temp->data = data; 
    temp->left = NULL; 
    temp->right = NULL; 
    return temp; 
}
```

That's C style. C++ style would be:

```
struct Node { 
    int data_; 
    Node *left_ = nullptr;
    Node *right_ = nullptr;

    explicit Node(int data) : data_(data) {}
};
```

Then when you want a new heap-allocated node, you don't call `newNode(42)` — you call `new Node(42)`! Or, a good habit you should get into: call `std::make_unique<Node>(42)` to get back a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Notice that I added sigils to your data members (`data_` etc) to distinguish them from non-member variables; and I declared no more than one variable per line to reduce reader confusion.

---

```
void inorder(Node *&root) 
{ 
    if (root != NULL) 
    { 
        inorder(((root)->left)); 
        printf("%d \n", (root)->data); 
        inorder(((root)->right)); 
    } 
}
```

Several things weird here. First, you have a bunch of unnecessary parentheses. `(root)` is the same thing as `root`. Second, you're passing `root` by *non-const reference*, even though you don't intend to modify it. Third, very minor nit, you're using C-style `NULL` instead of `nullptr`. Fourth, why do you print a space before the newline? Fixed up:

```
void inorder(const Node *root)
{
    if (root != nullptr) {
        inorder(root->left); 
        printf("%d\n", root->data); 
        inorder(root->right); 
    } 
}
```

Remember to remove the redundant parentheses in places like `insert(((node)->right),value)`. It's much easier to read as `insert(node->right, value)`.

Comment: Yeah the unnecessary parentheses came from when I was editing from the previous solution. Also, surprisingly was not aware of putting a constructor / destructor into the struct, thanks for pointing that out to me. Much needed feedback.

Comment: Actually, leaving `Node` without *any* user-declared ctors and functions is much better: It **doesn't have any invariants**, as much as anyone might pretend, and they only get in the way of implementing the list efficiently and correctly, which *does*.

Comment: @Deduplicator "A node always has the data set" is quite obviously a (very simple) invariant which the constructor nicely enforces. And in what way does it make the implementation harder?

Comment: @Voo Well, first I would always put the links first. Then, a new `Node` is created with `new Node{nullptr, nullptr, {args...}}`, irrespective what `{args...}` is, even a function-call, and whether the data-type can be copied, moved, or only in-place-constructed.

Comment: @Deduplicator Wouldn't that work just as well with a constructor if you use the right signature?

Comment: @Voo Then you need a variadic-template forwarding-constructor. A lot of boilerplate for no use, imho, especially as aggregate-initialisation already works. Also, iif you have at least one layer of forwarding the function-call cannot create the return-value directly at the target, though you will probably have that anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator is wrong: Providing a constructor is obviously correct (especially for this programmer's level of expertise). Besides the "Node's data is always set" invariant, there are at least two more: "Node's left pointer is always initialized (never garbage)" and "Node's right pointer is always initialized (never garbage)." If `Node` were an internal implementation detail of some larger `List` type, then making it a POD struct might be a reasonable optimization; but remember that correctness trumps _premature_ optimization. (That said, Deduplicator's _answer_ deserves more upvotes. :))

Comment: @Quuxplusone Also, why the use of "explicit" before the constructor in the struct?

Comment: @Pulse: The keyword `explicit` should go on *every* constructor and conversion operator in your programs, unless you want to enable an implicit conversion (in this case, from `int` to `Node`). Implicit conversions are sometimes useful (e.g. from `const char *` to `std::string`) but vastly more often are a source of surprising behavior and bugs.

Answer (score 5):

1. I would have expected an empty line between your includes and the declaration of `Node`.
2. You seem inordinately fond of having extra-whitespace at the end of lines. Loose it, both in the code and in the output, as it at best irritates co-workers and diff.
3. Consider using smartpointers, specifically `std::unique_ptr` for the link- and root-pointer. That way, you won't leak your tree. Admittedly, not freeing might be an intentional optimisation for faster shutdown, but that seems unlikely.
   [Yes, you have as much recursion as in `inorder()`, using an explicit stack could avoid that. Or much more iteration. Or having back-pointers. Or a custom area-allocator.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE&t=15m57s)
4. As a matter of course, I would always put the links first in any kind of node-class.
5. `newNode` is very expansively written, and if the value_type isn't trivially constructible, might not be optimisable by the compiler from initialisation+assignment for all members to just initialisation. Why ask it to?

   ```
   Node* newNode(int value) {
       return new Node{value};
       // Or if you move the links: `new Node{nullptr, nullptr, value}`
       // With C++20: `new Node{.data = value}`
   }
   ```

   That can easily be used for non-copyable, non-movable, and even only in-place-constructible types.
6. Prefer `nullptr` for nullpointer-constants, if you actually need one. That is more type-safe, and sometimes enables additional optimisations.
7. Try to take advantage of references to simplify calling your functions.
8. `insert()` drops any duplicate values. Is that intentional? If so, that needs to be called out in a comment, or made more obvious from the code-structure!
9. `insert()` has no need to recurse:

   ```
   void insert(Node* &root, int value) {
       auto p = &root;
       while (*p && p[0]->data != value)
           p = p[0]->data > value ? &p[0]->left : &p[0]->right;
       if (!*p)
           *p = newNode(value);
   }
   ```
10. `inorder()` only needs to know the root-node, not where the pointer to it is saved. Also, it never modifies anything. Thus, it should accept `Node const*` or `Node const&`.
11. `inorder()` cannot throw by design, so mark it `noexcept`.
12. Try to minimize the level of indentation. Guards at the start of a function are quite idiomatic.
13. What does `inorder()` do in order? Ah, printing. So, why not call it `print_inorder()`?

    ```
    void print_inorder(const Node *root) noexcept {
        if (!root)
            return;
        print_inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d\n", root->data);
        print_inorder(root->right);
    }
    ```
14. Some would suggest favoring iostreams over stdio for added type-safety, but there are downsides for that too.
15. `return 0;` is implicit for `main()`.
16. Naturally, for any further use you would want to wrap your data-structure in its own class-template with members for observing, modifying, iterating, and ctors / dtor for enforcing the invariants and manage the resources. But ensuring full re-usability is probably far out-of-scope at the moment.

Comment: On #3, I think it's worth mentioning that if you use `unique_ptr` for the links, then [the destructor of `Node` becomes recursive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE&t=15m57s), which means it's probably not a good idea for real code (but is still a good suggestion for OP to think about and understand how it'd work).

Comment: The ` extra-whitespace at the end of lines` This is more important than it looks (it feels trivial but I agree with deduplicator that it is important). People specifically set their editors to show extra white space at then end of lines.

Comment: Relying on the order of members in such an implicit and hidden way for #3 strikes me as an awful, awful maintenance burden for very little benefit. Using the c++20 syntax is fine though (that one's really only in c++20? I guess before it was just a really popular extension?)

Comment: @Voo Yes, it's a popular extension and C got it earlier with C99.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah I know that C had it for years, I just assumed C++ would've gotten it around c++11 or possibly 14 as well. Well, better late than never.

Answer (score 2):

In insert, You don't need to both catch the value (i.e. `((*node)->left = insert(&((*node)->left),value);`) returned AND pass the pointers by reference (i.e. double pointers). That is redundant. Choose one or the other.